# Firefox isn't using my download manager (flash videos)

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, video, browser-addons, download-manager

I installed "Free Download Manager." I see the plugin in Tools->Add-ons (it doesn't have any options).  I use several different flash video downloaders, because I haven't found one that works period on any site.  When I save the video with two I tried, they are being downloaded by Firefox's default download manager (which means simultaneously - which is why I installed the download manager - I need them to download one at a time - in a prioritized queue.)  [I used to use Flashgot (long ago), and it worked with some download manager I had installed - but over time it failed to see most videos.  I installed Flashgot again, and it still fails to see anything but images and video ads.]

Currently, I have to manually start Free Download Manager (from outside of Firefox), start the download in Firefox, stop it, copy the link location from Firefox's download menu, and then add it manually in Free Download Manager.  Yuck.  Do I need a different download manager (that takes over - recommendations?), or did I somehow install this one wrong or miss a setting somewhere in Firefox?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

For flash downloads I use [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3006) which uses its own queue:

> DownloadHelper also allows you to
>   download files one by one, so that you
>   keep bandwidth to surf for other stuff
>   to download.

A very good general download manager which I use is [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201) which has a fully configurable queue.

I have both of these installed and they do not clash.

Information on using DownThemAll!:

The first time you use it you only get the DownThemAll! option in addition to the standard Open / Save options.

[image]

This brings up the DownThemAll! dialog where you can set the location to save to.

[image]

The download is then added to the dTa queue.

The next time you click a link it will offer you the dTa OneClick! option to save it to the previously selected location without the intermediate dialog - straight to the queue.

Comment: Video DownloadHelper doesn't work on many sites, so I uninstalled it a while back. I did try it again a couple days ago - it's still not useful to me.

Comment: I installed DownThemAll.  I went through all the options.  It doesn't take over and manage downloads, Firefox's default is still being used.

Comment: After 1.5 hours, a download stopped, and restarting failed.  I reloaded the page, and it's reloading.  If I only could find a download manager to replaces Firefox's, so I could resume a download. The link is exactly the same, and it had to start all over.

Comment: You have to select DownThemAll when you click a download link

Comment: DownThemAll supports resuming of downloads

Comment: I've added some instructions on using dTa to my answer.